# Ruby on Rails Application Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

**What Rails application templates show best practices for setting up a new Ruby on Rails application?**

I'm interested in two things.

1. Which application templates are
   designed well (modular and easily
   customized)?
2. Which offer the best (or most
       popular) combination of components
       needed in a typical Rails app?

I'm asking about scripts that are used with the `rails new app_name -m` command to generate an application.

---

I've looked at some examples. What do you think of these?

> [greendog99/greendog-rails-template](https://github.com/greendog99/greendog-rails-template)
>   Devise, RSpec, Factory Girl, jQuery,
>   Haml, Sass, Compass, Git, rvm, HTML5
>   Boilerplate, plus a layout. Uses
>   subtemplates for easy customizing.
>
> [dcrec1/rails3_template](https://github.com/dcrec1/rails3_template)
>   Devise (with Cucumber steps),
>   Cucumber, RSpec, Factory Girl, Haml,
>   Compass, jQuery, Git, Formtastic, a
>   layout, and more. Uses
>   subtemplates for easy customizing.
>
> [aentos/rails3-templates](https://github.com/aentos/rails3-templates)
>   Devise or Authlogic or OmniAuth,
>   Cucumber, Capybara, RSpec, Factory
>   Girl, Shoulda, jQuery, Haml, Compass,
>   960 grid or Blueprint, Capistrano or
>   Heroku or Inploy, Git, plus a layout.
>   Uses subtemplates for easy
>   customizing.
>
> [rubyx/rails3_template](https://github.com/rubyx/rails3_template)
>   PostgreSQL, Devise, Cucumber with
>   Selenium and Capybara, RSpec with
>   Machinist and Faker, JQuery, Simple
>   Form, Haml, SASS, Git, rvm, Google
>   analytics (optional), Hoptoad for
>   issue tracking (optional),
>   TellThemWhen for downtime
>   notifications (optional). With a
>   description of the recipe in the
>   README.
>
> [perfectline/template-bucket](https://github.com/perfectline/template-bucket)
>   Cucumber, RSpec, jQuery, Haml or
>   Jammit, Capistrano, Git, rvm, plus a
>   layout. Uses subtemplates for easy
>   customizing.
>
> [leshill/rails3-app](https://github.com/leshill/rails3-app)
>   Cucumber, RSpec, Factory Girl or
>   Fabrication, Haml, jQuery, Git, rvm.

These Rails 2.3 projects look like they were once popular but haven't been updated since 2009 or 2010:

> [jm/rails-templates](https://github.com/jm/rails-templates)
>
> [ffmike/BigOldRailsTemplate](https://github.com/ffmike/BigOldRailsTemplate)

Answer (score 1):

We develop and use [our template](https://github.com/lab2023/rails-template) . You can check and use. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Thoughtbot's Suspenders project looks interesting - http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/2315306436/fishing-for-trout-in-our-suspenders

Especially with the addition of Trout to update core suspenders files at a later date

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the [rails-templater](https://github.com/kfaustino/rails-templater) gem with good results. It does not currently have rvm support, so if you create gemsets for each Rails project, be sure to create and use the gemset prior to running the wizard, otherwise some unsuspecting gemset will get a bunch of unwanted gems.

```
$ rvm gemset create myapp_name
$ rvm gemset use myapp_name
$ templater myapp_name
```